# Read line by line in java

Tags: java, xml, servlets, request, byte

I'm receiving a xml file from a POST.
I'm trying to read what's inside the xml file but the answers I get aren't logic to me.
I wish to only read the third line,  but it seems that's the only one my program don't want to read.

**.JAVA:**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    int line=0;
    byte[] buffer=new byte[1000];
    while(line<5) {
        request.getInputStream().readLine(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        line++;
    }
    String name = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

**.XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Trias xmlns:siri="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri" xmlns="http://www.vdv.de/trias" xmlns:ns3="http://www.ifopt.org.uk/acsb" xmlns:ns4="http://www.ifopt.org.uk/ifopt" xmlns:ns5="http://datex2.eu/schema/1_0/1_0" version="1.2">
    <siri:CheckStatusRequest>
        <siri:RequestTimestamp>2018-03-12T16:36:30.002+01:00</siri:RequestTimestamp>
```

Comment: You really don't want to read XML in terms of lines -- major frame of reference confusion and unnecessary complexity that way.  Use an XML parser instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading with `readLine()` you should check the return value to ensure you are not reading past the end of the stream.

```
int line = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
while (line < 5) {
    int read = request.getInputStream().readLine(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    if (read < 0) {
        break; // end of stream reachead
    }
    line++;
}
```

However it would be better to read the XML with a parser e.g. [SAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html). That way you can focus on business task and don't have to handle framework tasks e.g. [XML normalization](https://www.w3.org/2008/xmlsec/Drafts/xml-norm/Overview.html).

Answer (score 1):

You don’t want to assume the third line contains the content of interest.  Newlines are not required between XML elements.  For example, the request body could be delivered as:

```
<Trias …><siri:CheckStatusRequest><siri:RequestTimestamp>2018-03-12T16:36:30.002+01:00</siri:RequestTimestamp></siri:CheckStatusRequest></Trias>
```

(Trias attributes omitted for clarity.)

Java has plenty of tools for reading XML.  In your case, [XPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) is probably the easiest:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String timeStr = xpath.evaluate("//*[local-name()='RequestTimestamp']",
    new InputSource(request.getInputStream()));
OffsetDateTime timestamp = OffsetDateTime.parse(timeStr);
```